# Add New Input Field in Wordpress Post Entry

Tags: wordpress

I am hoping someone can help with this.

I am a Wordpress newbie, and I have heard about how great Wordpress nowadays.

I have a quick question, how do I add or modify the Post form entry so that I can add more input fields like drop down, checkboxes, or radio buttons to the Post form page.

Any guidance or references that I can look into will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use custom post field for plugin for this purpose
 download this [Here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) after that you can fetch the input field with

```
get_post_meta($post->ID,'field name');
```

Comment: Inside the loop you can just use get_field('field_name');

Comment: @omerFarooq yeah .. agree with you. you can use this . for more reference read the plugin document . very useful plugin for this type of tasks.